# Move "hex" on target's death

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Alright, so the description of the "hex" spell states the following:

> [...] If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to curse a new creature. [...]

So, the way I understand it, the "subsequent turn" does not have to be *directly* afterwards, right? I mean, if you do something else for 3 rounds, the 4th round would still technically be *a* subsequent spell, correct?

Therefore, let's say I cast this spell in the first round of combat, finish my enemies together with the rest of my party and exit combat. Then, thirty minutes later, we enter combat again (and are therefore still within hex's max duration, even if cast at its lowest level).

So my question: Can I still move my hex to an enemy of my choice in this situation? Provided that I kept up concentration for the whole time, of course (which some super-strict DMs might punish), and didn't enter an antimagic field or encountered anything else that would cause the spell to end.

Thanks in advance, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, Hex can be reapplied on *any* subsequent turn.

Hex is not limited to *next* turn, just *a subsequent* turn. So yes, after your target dies, you can use a bonus action on *any* turn within the spell's duration to reapply it to another enemy as long as you maintain concentration on it.

This is supported by [a Mike Mearls tweet.](https://twitter.com/Matsiv1/status/922591861327441920?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sageadvice.eu%2F2017%2F12%2F12%2Fif-hex-can-be-moved-on-any-subsequent-turn-in-the-duration-does-that-include-out-of-combat-situations%2F)

> Q: If hex can be moved on "any subsequent turn" in the duration does that include "out of combat" situations and following combats?
>
> A: Yes

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, so long as you keep concentration**

This is a question that was answered by the development team

> Harbinger of Doom If Concentration is unbroken, is it intended for
>   3rd+ lv Hex to be cast once & persist thru multiple encounters in a
>   day?
>
> Jeremy Crawford 
>   Yes, that's intended.
>   https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/10/02/hex-concentration/